# Run TFS query in the past?

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, tfs-2015

I've some simple queries in my Team Foundation Server 2015, .e.g,. to count the open WorkItems. Now I want to track this in history and want to know, how many WorkItems were open one week or one month ago?

So, can I run a query in the past to a date x? Or is the only way to get such historical data to start today and write down all values from now on to have the history in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This will only work in VSO or TFS 2015+**

You can use the queries in new REST API's with the ASOF operator.

You would do an HTTP POST with content like below

```
{
  "query": "Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State] From WorkItems Where [System.AssignedTo] = @Me AND [State] <> 'Closed' AND [State] <> 'Done' AND [State] <> 'Removed'  ASOF '01 Sep 2015' order by [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority] asc, [System.CreatedDate] desc"
}
```

to the url

http://[Server]/[Collection]/[TeamProject]/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=1.0

and then you will get a response back with each work item Id that that query returns and then you can get the details for those work items using the other Rest API that takes in a list of work item Ids (look for **_apis/wit/WorkItems** on the Rest API link below).

So you would need to use code and not just the UI but you shouldn't need to use the object model to do this.

Rest API Queries - http://r3f.co/1g5cYIw

ASOF - http://r3f.co/1g5cSRg

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to use TFS work item queries to get historical work items. You need to work with TFS API.

Please check this blog for the details on how to get work item histories via API.

http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/08/21/tfs-sdk-work-item-history-visualizer-using-tfs-api.aspx